# Jquery UI timepicker add-on firing parsing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

I keep on get an error when using this the JQuery time picker add-on from here trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ I don't know what's wrong with it and no matter what I do it doesn't change.

my code goes something like this

JavaScript

```
var queryDate new date(document.getElementById('tempcontainer').value);
$(function()){
    $("#tempcontainer").datetimepicker({
        timeFormat:"hh:mm:ss",
        dateFormat:"d M yy",
        defaultValue:queryDate, ... etc
```

HTML

```
<input id=tempcontainer name=fld-date-24 value="28 September 2013">
```

I'm getting an error like this:

Error parsing the date/time string: Unexpected literal at position 6 
date/time string = 28 September 2013
timeFormat: hh:mm:ss
dateFormat: d M yy

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: 'tempcontaine', should be 'tempcontainer' and $(#tempcontainer) should be $("#tempcontainer"). Is this also in your code, or just here?

Comment: sorry yes those were just typos I will change them. I am working on a JSfiddle for you Donovan, it may take some time not working out as I thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format is 'd M yy' which would have to be '28 Sep 2013', so when it hits the 't' in September it throws an error.

Try 'd MM yy' instead.

You can find details on all the datepicker format options at http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/.